# Зіпсутий чи зіпсований?

Tags: вживання-слів, фонетика

На http://ukrlit.org знайшла:

ЗІПСУ́ТИЙ, рідше ЗОПСУ́ТИЙ, а, е, розм. Те саме, що зіпсо́ваний. Кінь утомлений, копита Розкуті, розбиті, Сіделечко мережане Зопсуте, невкрите (Шевч., II, 1963, 382); Він був не злий хлопець з природи, але бездонно зіпсутий (Фр., IV, 1950, 371).

Найчастіше чую "зіпсований", а не "зіпсутий". Цікава форма - "зопсутий".

Яке слово доречно вживати в розмовній мові? Яке є літературним? Чи обидві форми правильні?

Comment: Поясніть, будь ласка, що саме вам незрозуміло? У словнику прямо написано, що "зіпсутий" і "зопсутий" - це розмовні слова, а "зіпсований" - не має особливостей вживання. Поки ставлю мінус.

Answer (score 2):

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/zipsovanyj) знаходимо слово **зіпсований** без будь-яких позначок, які б вказували на особливості вживання (однак, вказана паралельна форма вживання **ЗОПСОВАНИЙ** з позначкою *рідше*, отже це слово краще уникати там, де є вимоги лише нормативного вживання слів):

> **ЗІПСО́ВАНИЙ**, рідше **ЗОПСО́ВАНИЙ**, а, е.
>
> 1. Дієпр. пас. мин. ч. до зіпсувати, зопсувати.
> 2. у знач. прикм. Який зіпсувався, став непридатним для використання, вживання.
> 3. у знач. прикм. Який змінився на гірше, погіршав.
> 4. у знач. прикм. З поганими нахилами, звичками; розбещений.

Слово [зіпсутий](http://sum.in.ua/s/zipsutyj) можна вживати лише в розмовній мові:

> **ЗІПСУ́ТИЙ**, рідше **ЗОПСУ́ТИЙ**, а, е, розм. Те саме, що зіпсований.

Слово **зопсутий** вживається рідше, ніж **зіпсутий** (і лише у розмовній мові).

Отже, **зіпсований** **(зопсований)** є літературними, однак, позначка *рідше* коло слова **зопсований** обмежує все-таки його вживання у нормативних документах. **Зіпсутий (зопсутий)** можна вживати лише у розмовній мові.